# How to override the tree node template in ExtJS 5?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

I'm working around [a bug](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?287005-Javascript-anchors-HOSE-all-HtmlField-components-in-IE9) in ExtJS 5.0, and to do so, I need to change the template used by the TreePanel.

Currently, nodes use normal anchors for all URLs, including Javascript calls:

```
<a href="javascript:doSomething()" role="link" class="blah">label</a>
```

For JavaScript URIs, I need to use onclick instead to avoid the bug:

```
<a onclick="doSomething()" role="link" class="blah">label</a>
```

I'm trying the following override and it appears to have no impact on the HTML:

```
Ext.override("Ext.tree.Column", {
    cellTpl: [ "Hello World" ]
});
```

What am I missing ? Shouldn't this override `cellTpl`?

Comment: Figured it out... shouldn't quote the name of the class I'm overriding, despite online examples to the contrary. *sigh*.

Comment: You quote the class name when using the define syntax. `Ext.define('MyOverride', { override: 'Ext.tree.Column' });`